# can bfg-repo-cleaner list affected files before deleting them

Tags: bfg-repo-cleaner

From the command line option I can not see that there is a way to see what bfg will do before doing it.

If I run this command:

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M --replace-text banned.txt repo.git
```

Can I get a list of files larger than 1M before actual deleting them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/17 for a discussion on a dry-run feature.

Essense of my comments there: since Git makes it super-cheap to make additional local clones where you can perform test-runs of BFG, and this provides you with real output you can verify in addition to a report, that is superior to having a report-only or dry-run mode.

Just make an additional local clone of the repo, run BFG, then read the reports produced and examine the repo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. A dry run would be nice, but I can live with cloning the repo. Any way bfg works really well.